# How to unset value array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
array( 
    "tracker"=> array( 
            0=> array( 
                0=> "[" ,
                1=> "asiangames" ,
                2=> "," ,
                3=> "asiangames2018" ,
                4=> "," ,
                5=> "asian" ,
                6=> "]" 
            ),
            1=> array( 
                0=> "[" ,
                1=> "2019gantipresiden" ,
                2=> "]" 
            ) 
    ) 
)
```

How to unset value, if not word in PHP for example in this array
unset value `[` and `]` and `,`, `?`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260468/php-unset-in-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: here array: array(1) { ["tracker"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "[" [1]=> string(10) "asiangames" [2]=> string(1) "," [3]=> string(14) "asiangames2018" [4]=> string(1) "," [5]=> string(5) "asian" [6]=> string(1) "]" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "[" [1]=> string(17) "2019gantipresiden" [2]=> string(1) "]" } } }

Comment: @Ade How are you generating this array.  I reckon I would fix the data earlier in your code.  Show me, I'll help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP removing values meeting specific conditon from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951715/php-removing-values-meeting-specific-conditon-from-array)

Comment: @nageen As I have demonstrated in my answer, `array_diff()` is a superior/cleaner/more direct call to `array_filter()` or nested iterattions of `unset()`.

Comment: @Ade In the future, please include your best coding attempt with your question. Normally, I wouldn't post an answer until a question includes code, but AlivetoDie sabotaged that stance by offering a solution that I found to be unrefined. I say this so that you can ask upvote-worthy questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `foreach()` like below:-

```
$remove_values = array('[',']',',');

foreach($your_array['tracker'] as &$value){
  foreach($value as $key=>$val){
     if(in_array($val,$remove_values)){
       unset($value[$key]);
     }
  }
}

print_r($your_array);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/1FaO1

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a function that does this task for you in one eloquent call for a clean, direct snippet.

[array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Iterate each subarray in `tracker` and apply the "blacklist" of values as the 2nd parameter in `array_diff()`.  The `&` before `$tracker` in the `foreach()` declaration makes the variable "modifiable by reference" -- effectively, this means that new data will be applied to the original array's `$tracker` and not a copy of the original input array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v93SD))

```
$array = [
    "tracker" => [
        ["[", "asiangames", ",", "asiangames2018", ",", "asian", "]"],
        ["[", "2019gantipresiden", "]"]
    ]
];

foreach ($array["tracker"] as &$tracker) {
    $tracker = array_diff($tracker, ["[", ",", "]"]);
}

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'tracker' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      1 => 'asiangames',
      3 => 'asiangames2018',
      5 => 'asian',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      1 => '2019gantipresiden',
    ),
  ),
)
```